# Au Pair in France OFII question

Tags: tickets, france, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, ofii

I am living in France (have been here just about 2 months) and have an au pair contract that runs from September 15 2013 until August 2014 (long stay visa). I have the visa in my passport, but it just became apparent to me that I am missing one step: the medical appointment with the [OFII (French Office for Immigration and Integration)](http://www.ofii.fr/defaut.php3?lang=en) and my visa stamp validating my long stay visa. When I realized this, it came as blessing more than an "oh no" moment, as the au pair experience with this family is really not how they presented it to me, and I am feeling very ready to go back home to the USA. Here is my question: if I simply ignore this OFII paperwork and wait for my 90 days to come to a close, will my departure from the country be necessary as my long stay visa no longer be valid, or will my host family simply call the OFII and get it sorted out? Note that I will be bringing this to my family's attention AFTER I have been in the country 90 days. I'm just curious if my long stay visa will legally be voided at that point, or if it's an easy fix even after my 90 days have ended.

Comment: And if anyone will be wondering: my family has turned out to be a rather overbearing set of parents who are taking advantage of my living in the house. I am terrible at confrontation and it is even worse if I try to do it in another language, especially as they have very strong personalities and will bulldoze anything I say. SO I would be very happy if it turns out me not going to the OFII gives me a legal reason to leave, as I do not think I will be brave enough to have the conversation otherwise and will have a very tough year here.

Comment: In general, messing up with the customs is way worse than dealing with random people. Waiting for French customs to kick you out will most likely hinder you from coming back to Schengen area, i.e. most of Europe, either as a tourist or worker. I suppose if you have problems with your employer, discuss it with your employer or resign, or just leave.

Comment: @Vince: I think you mean messing up with immigration. Customs is to do with bring things into a country but it's very common to confuse the two, we even have a recent question on this: [What is the difference between customs and immigration?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21005)

Comment: Sorry @jenniferallisontodaro but travel.SE has a long standing policy of not handling expat questions. As your question is about paperwork regarding working overseas rather than going there, getting home, being a tourist, etc it's not our field of expertise. Some people are trying to start an expats.SE for questions just like yours though so please consider supporting it even though you can't ask a question there yet: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates

Comment: +1 to hippietrail comment but beside the terminology I think @Vince has a point: The way I understand your question, you intend to wait until such time when you are effectively illegally in France (overstayed your visa-free stay for 90 days and without a valid long-stay visa). Whether this can be fixed or not, it's just inviting trouble. What don't you just quit? Formally, you have to give your notice and it's also nicer to give the family time to find alternative arrangements. But even if things are so bad that you just pack your things and leave, there isn't much that could happen to you.

Comment: If this question still matters to you, the [Expatriates SE site has now launched](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), and you may wish to re-ask it there if you'd like to get an answer