# Norwegian Air Shuttle into Oakland Internatonal Airport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, oak

Do passengers coming off the Norwegian Air Shuttle from Stockholm into Oakland International Airport clear customs before they get their checked luggage or after?

Comment: In reading the answer below, and any other answers, please keep in mind [the difference between customs and immigration](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21005/what-is-the-difference-between-customs-and-immigration).

Comment: This question is illogical. If you cleared customs before collecting your bags, how would customs check your bags?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of pre-clearance like at Dublin, Shannon or Vancouver? No such thing at any of the Norwegian departure airports: Stockholm, Oslo, Coppenhagen, London Gatwick.

Answer (score 4):

You always collect your baggage before Customs, but after Immigration in the US (most other locations too).

Customs, Agriculture, and possibly other Federal or State Agencies may chose to inspect all your belongings, include your checked baggage.

Depending how CPB chooses to staff and enforce, the distinction may be very subtle with "Customs" being handing over your Declaration.