# Does an emergency passport from an embassy count as a document issued by another country?

Tags: usa, esta

I am a UK national planning a trip to New York City.

On the ESTA form, specifically the *'Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?'*, should I include a one-use emergency passport I was issued in Croatia after my passport was stolen in 2014?

Not sure it counts as it was a UK document, issued by a UK embassy, just happened to be in Croatia.

Comment: British consular staff are crown servants and British Embassies belong to HM.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question is asking about documents issued *by* another country, not those issued *in* another country. A document issued by UK authorities is issued by the UK, regardless of the location.

Comment: Thank you, that was my hunch but I wasn't 100%. Best wishes

Comment: EU consulates can now issue emergency travel documents to citizens of other EU countries, so it might be more common in the future for Europeans to have documents issued by third countries.

Comment: Not only is a document from a consulate issued _by_ the country, it is also issued _in_ that country, as consulates are wholly that country's soil.

Comment: @AlexWillison: No, consulates and other diplomatic posts have specific _diplomatic protections_ that limit the day-to-day authority the host country's government can exercise over them, but they are still, fundamentally, part of the host country's territory

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for the clarification!  Is this the difference between a consulate and an embassy?

Comment: @AlexWillison No. Embassies are also not the sovereign territory of the represented country. This is a common misconception. The difference between an embassy and a consulate is that the former is the main diplomatic post. There is one only, led by the ambassador. Consulates are secondary; there can be and often are more than one, headed by a consul.

Comment: @AlexWillison Asked and answered at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/whats-the-difference-between-embassies-and-consulates

Comment: @phoog I thought embassies were the representative of one government to another (e.g., call up the embassy to work on this treaty issue), and that consulates were the representative of one government to the people in another country (e.g., people go to the consulate to get visas).  Embassies should be close to the government seat and consulates should be near population centers.

Comment: @emory that's essentially true (when one gets a visa from an embassy, for example, embassy one usually gets it from the "consular section"), but consular duties also include serving citizens of the sending country (issuing passports, for example, or providing support to those who have been arrested). Consulates also promote the sending country's commercial interests and represent it in other ways.